# Using Redux Reselect and PureComponent - Nothing updates

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist, reselect

I'm using React Redux with Reselect to select a list of team members and bind it to a FlatList. The FlatList uses a PureComponent to render each item.

The selector creates a flat object for each team member, no nested data, but when any of the values in a team member changes the PureComponent doesn't update.

I can't put all the code here but here is some simpler pseudo-code to show what I'm doing...

**Getting the team**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        teamMembers: getTeamMembers(state) // This is a Reselect selector
    }
}
```

**Creating the FlatList**

```
<FlatList
    ref={(ref) => { this.listRef = ref }}
    data={this.props.teamMembers}
    renderItem={({item}) => <TeamMemberListItem player={item}></TeamMemberListItem>}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.playerId.toString()}
    removeClippedSubviews
    disableVirtualization
/>
```

**The Item Component**

```
class TeamMemberListItem extends PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {  }
    }

    render() { 

        return (
            <View style={styles.teamMemberListItem}>
                <Text>{this.props.player.presenceState}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Once the team has loaded there's a delay and the presence for each team member loads, the store is updated, the selector runs again but the listItems don't update.

So, what I don't understand is, when does a PureComponent update? Even if changinging the "top level" or "non-nested" data doesn't cause a re-render, when would it? Is there a way I can get it to work using my current selector or will I have to revert to using a normal Component and put up with YellowBox errors all the time saying my FlatList isn't optimized?

Comment: what does the `FlatList` component internals look like? When you run the code, does its `teamMembers` prop get populated with data from the store?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I get a list of team members, but once their presence state loads none of the items update to show the green dot which indicates they're online.

Comment: do `TeamMemberListItem`s render as intended when using a regular `Component`?

Comment: Yes, I have switched it to a normal component for now and they all update.

Comment: PureComponent -> React. PureComponent ?